# Click to add sentence + array number and result with <br> on each line

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm starting to learn how to code and I guess this is really easy for you but it's been VERY hard for me to find out on how to do it.

I want to be able to add a number on and store that number and get a result like this:

Lets say I typed number 2, then 34, then 65 and 234.

Result would be like:

```
<integer>2</integer>
<integer>34</integer>
<integer>65</integer>
<integer>234</integer>
```

Do you see what i mean? I need to have the integer string plus whatever number I type and the result would need to add an br.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numb").value);
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  var array = [];

  array.push("<integer>" + x + "</integer>");
  console.log(array);
  result.innerHTML = array;

}
```

```html
<h1>Integer</h1>
<h2>Enter number</h2>

<input type="number" id="numb">
<button id="submitbutton" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>


<h1>
  <div>Result: <span id="result"> xxx </span></div>
</h1>
```

Comment: Move `var array = [];` outside the function You create a new array each time. I created you a snippet and fixed the spelling of Integer

Comment: @mplungjan is 100% correct but I thought I would add that you should probably read up on scope and closures just to give you a better understanding of why simply moving the array declaration out of the function solves your problem. https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript

Comment: Yes @mplungjan ty for that it partially worked. The result Im getting is still only the number I typed and not the whole "<interger>array</interger>" u see? also need the <br> after every .push on the array! :(

Comment: `result.innerHTML = array.join("<br/>");`

Comment: ty once again! Now I have the br but the result is still only the number! Is there a way for me to add "<interger></interger>" on each result as well please?

Comment: @Marcell check the answer that mplungjan submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. move the var array out of the function scope to not create a new one each time
2. Join the array
3. Use CSS to markup your integer tag

PS: If you want to SEE the tags. change the code below to

```
array.push("&lt;integer>" + parseInt(x) + "&lt;/integer>");
```

Here the tags are styled instead

```js
var array = [];

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("numb").value.trim();
  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  if (!isNaN(x) && x!="") { // test valid number
    array.push("<integer>" + parseInt(x) + "</integer>");
   //  console.log(array);
    result.innerHTML = array.join("<br/>");
  }

}
```

```css
integer { font-weight:bold; color:teal }
```

```html
<h3>Integer</h3>
<h4>Enter number</h4>
<input type="number" id="numb">
<button id="submitbutton" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>


<h1>
  <div>Result: <span id="result"> xxx </span></div>
</h1>
```

Comment: I see what you mean! but when I click on submit all I get are the numbers I typed and dont have "<interger></interger>" in the middle! Weirdly enough on the console.log I can see that but not on the result page! :(

Comment: `<integer>` is a tag. It is not understood by the browser unless you give it a style. See my <integer> is coloured

Comment: If you want to see the tags, change to `"&lt;integer>"+x+"&lt;integer>";`

Comment: IT WORKED! OMG you are amazing! Thank you VERY MUCH! Im really happy! thank you! :)